# Map through an array to form a line graph

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, web, ecmascript-6

i want to make a reusable line chart component from a data. Currently, i have created the line chart component, but it is still not reusable.

Here is the Line Chart component which isn't reusable. Note that the "LineGraph" is repeated for every dataKey

`

```js
import {LineChart as ChartLine, Line as LineGraph, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend, Bar, ResponsiveContainer} from 'recharts'

export class LineChart extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <div className="bar-chart-container">
        <large style={{margin:'30px 50px'}}>{this.props.label}</large>
        <ResponsiveContainer width='100%' height={250}>
          <ChartLine width={680} height={250} data={this.props.data}>
            <XAxis dataKey="name" />
            <YAxis />
            <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
            <Tooltip />
            <Legend iconType="circle" iconSize={8}/>
            <LineGraph type="monotone" dataKey="BSD" stroke="#f8aa27"/>
            <LineGraph type="monotone" dataKey="FSD" stroke="#94dea9"/>
            <LineGraph type="monotone" dataKey="SMS" stroke="#795548"/>
            <LineGraph type="monotone" dataKey="TDMO" stroke="#0099ff"/>
            <LineGraph type="monotone" dataKey="CEM" stroke="#642bb6"/>
          </ChartLine>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

`

And here is the data

```js
<LineChart
   label="SPI HISTORY"
   data={[
         { name: 'JAN', BSD: 0.3, FSD: 0.6 , SMS: 1.2 , TDMO: 1.4 , CEM: 0.8 },
         { name: 'FEB', BSD: 0.5, FSD: 0.3 , SMS: 1.1 , TDMO: 1.8 , CEM: 1.0 },
         { name: 'MAR', BSD: 0.2, FSD: 0.4 , SMS: 1.1 , TDMO: 1.7 , CEM: 1.2 },
         { name: 'APR', BSD: 0.3, FSD: 0.9 , SMS: 0.7 , TDMO: 1.4 , CEM: 1.1 },
         { name: 'MAY', BSD: 0.6, FSD: 1.0 , SMS: 0.8 , TDMO: 1.6 , CEM: 1.2 },
         { name: 'JUN', BSD: 0.4, FSD: 1.5 , SMS: 0.9 , TDMO: 0.8 , CEM: 1.1 },
         { name: 'JUL', BSD: 0.6, FSD: 1.2 , SMS: 1.5 , TDMO: 1.0 , CEM: 1.6 },
         { name: 'AUG', BSD: 0.9, FSD: 1.3 , SMS: 1.8 , TDMO: 0.3 , CEM: 1.5 },
         { name: 'SEP', BSD: 0.7, FSD: 0.9 , SMS: 1.3 , TDMO: 0.5 , CEM: 1.6 },
         { name: 'OCT', BSD: 0.8, FSD: 1.0 , SMS: 1.6 , TDMO: 1.0 , CEM: 1.4 },
         { name: 'NOV', BSD: 0.5, FSD: 0.3 , SMS: 1.7 , TDMO: 0.8 , CEM: 1.1 },
        { name: 'DEC', BSD: 0.2, FSD: 0.4 , SMS: 1.6 , TDMO: 1.5 , CEM: 1.2 }
     ]}/>
```

And here is the output:
[Graph Rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3jwJ.jpg)

How do i make it reusable so i don't have to write each "LineGraph" for each data (BSD, FSD, SMS, TDMO , CEM) and so i can use this component if the given data is different? Thank you very much!

edit: Docs for the line chart module
http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/LineChart

Comment: Which plugin are you using?

Comment: Oh yah forgot to mention it, here is the plugin i used to create the LineChart component http://recharts.org/#/en-US/api/LineChart   @AjaySuvarna

Comment: here what you want to reuse? Which part do you want to reuse?

Comment: Particularly the "<LineGraph>" part, i dont want to repeat like i did where i make "<LineGraph>" for each dataKey (BSD,FSD,SMS) . Basically, if i can fix that part, then i can reuse this whole LineChart component with whatever data i want (not just data that has BSD,FSD,SMS,TDMO).
PS: You can change the given data with whatever structure you like  @AjaySuvarna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing the props for each `LineGraph` in an array such as:

```
const lgProps = [
  { dataKey: 'BSD', 
    stroke : '#f8aa27'},
  { dataKey: 'FSD', 
    stroke : '#94dea9'},
    ... ]
```

Then you just can do:

```
...
<Tooltip />
{lgProps.map((props) => <LineGraph type="monotone" key={props.dataKey} dataKey={props.dataKey} stroke={props.stroke} />)}
</ChartLine>
...
```

What you’ll need is to transform the `data` prop you’re passing to `LineChart` to something fitting for the `LineGraph` components.

---

**Update:**

A way to do the last point would be:

```
export class LineChart extends Component{
  render(){
    const seriesNames = this.props.data[0].map((dataSeries) => Object.keys(dataSeries)).filter((attr) => attr !== 'name')
    ...
    <Tooltip />
    {seriesNames.map((seriesName) => <LineGraph type="monotone" key={seriesName} dataKey={seriesName} />)}
    </ChartLine>
    ...
    }
  }
```

You may add the colour as you see fit. A good idea would be to pass along with `data` the `lgProps` as detailed above, so the user of the component can choose what data series to see and the colour as well.

Comment: Ahh i see i see, hmm yeah, but how do i put the "numbers" into the lgProps? Can i pass an array inside the dataKey?

`const lgProps = [
  { dataKey: BSD {[0.3,0.4,0.7,0.5]}, 
    stroke : '#f8aa27'},
  { dataKey: FSD {[0.4,0.2,0.2,0.3]}, 
    stroke : '#94dea9'},
    ... ]`

Comment: No, that’s incorrect JavaScript. What you can do, though, is this:
    `const lgProps = [
      { dataKey: 'BSD',
        values: [0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5],
        stroke : '#f8aa27' },
      { dataKey: 'FSD',
        values: [0.4,0.2,0.2,0.3],
        stroke : '#94dea9'}, ... ]`

Comment: Remember that in JavaScript an object literal is made up of pairs `key: value`, where `key` is a string and `value` is either a number, a string, an array, a function, another object, `undefined` or `null`.

More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals

Comment: After having a look at Recharts API I think that what you want is to retrieve the `dataKey` from `data`: `data[0].map((dataSeries) => Object.keys(dataSeries)).filter((attr) => attr !== 'name')`. This will return an array with `['BSD', 'FSD', ...]`.

Another option is to pass a separate prop array where you specify which data series you want to display, in case you don’t want all of them (e.g. `<LineChart displaySeries={['TDMO', 'CEM']} ... />`) and you map `displaySeries` to `LineGraph` components.

Comment: Be aware that you’re doing two things:
1. In `<ChartLine width={680} height={250} data={this.props.data}>` you’re passing all the data to the chart.
2. With each `<LineGraph />` you’re specifying which series you want to display and in which colour.
So you don’t need the numbers in the LineGraph components.

Comment: Thank you very much for your willing to help Alif, i really appreciate it, okay i understand your last point ( i'm doing two things, passing all data to the chart) , but i'm a bit lost with retrieving the dataKey from data. Where should i put the returned value to? inside the <LineGraph /> ?

Comment: Ahhh okay i understand now. I've tried it and it works!
Thank you very much for your willing to help Alf! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No worries! Thanks for marking the answer as correct. Giving a bit more thought, if you really want your component to be truly reusable, I would add an extra optional prop to `LineChart`: `<LineChart label="SPI HISTORY" data={[...]} displaySeries=[{dataKey: 'FSD', color:'red'}, ...]/>` so you can specify what data series you want to see. If `displaySeries` is not present you default to all, as in the update.

Comment: Finally, as best practices go, you rename `LineChart` as `ChartLine` because you give that name to your component. I’d suggest you do `import {LineChart,...} from 'recharts'` and rename your component to e.g. `LineChartWrapper`.